# Haskell Kinds and Type Constraints

Tags: haskell, ghc

Say I have the following type class

```
class Silly (t :: * -> *) where
    -- details
```

I would like to be able to express the following constraint, but I'm not sure if it is even possible.

```
class (Silly s) => Willy (s t) where
    -- details
```

Basically I want to put a constraint on the type constructor, not the entire type. Is this even expressible? I'm not even sure what this kind of constraint would be called, so Google has been no help.

EDIT: I have a data type

```
data Reasoner logic atoms a = Reasoner { unReasoner :: MassAssignment atoms -> a }
```

that has an `Applicative` instance. I initially had a `run` function in order to make working with these Reasoners a bit easier, but since I want to take advantage of the free composability of applicatives, I defined a type class containing `run` instead, ala

```
class RunReasoner r where
    type MassType r
    type ResultType r
    run :: r -> MassType r -> ResultType r
```

with the following instances

```
instance RunReasoner (Reasoner l as a) where
    type MassType (Reasoner l as a) = MassAssignment as
    type ResultType (Reasoner l as a) = a
    run = -- details

instance (RunReasoner (r2 t)) => RunReasoner (Compose (Reasoner l1 as1) r2 t) where
    type MassType (Compose (Reasoner l1 as1) r2 t) = MassAssignment as1
    type ResultType (Compose (Reasoner l1 as1) r2 t) = r2 t
    run = -- details
```

so that I can write code such as

```
expression `run` mass1 `run` mass2 `run` ... `run` massN
```

This is all good for the most part, but I am now composing reasoners in other ways, and would prefer if the MassType were available from just the type constructor `Reasoner l as`, instead of having to have the full type instance `Reasoner l as a`. Therefore I was considering splitting the `RunReasoner` type class into two, since MassType does not depend on the final type parameter.

Comment: Could you give some more context on how you intend to use this? I'm pretty sure it's possible to achieve what you need quite simply, though it won't look like what you've written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make a standalone type family

```
type family MassType (r :: * -> *)
type instance MassType (Reasoner l as) = as
```

Comment: This simple answer made me rethink the way I was designing my types, and then led me to a working solution. Thank you.